# Next.js display data from DynamoDB

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

so im currently creating my first Website with Next.js.
Im using Amplify as a host for my website and my database.
However im having trouble to display the response im getting from my database.. I managed to log the response in my console which looks like this:

```
[
  Profile {
    name: 'firstActualUser',
    position: 'VIP',
    createdAt: '2022-02-08T15:39:01.527Z',
    updatedAt: '2022-02-08T15:39:07.527Z',
    _version: 1,
    _lastChangedAt: 6781253702551,
    _deleted: null
  }
]
```

My question is how do I render this response into my actual page? Currenty I log my response like this:

```
const externUsers = DataStore.query(Profile).then(users => console.log(users));
```

I thought I can simply access this response by just accessing the array like the following:

```
return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>Home</h1>
      <p>{externUsers[0].name}</p>
      <p>{externUsers[0].position}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

However that doesnt work and wouldnt be a nice solution anyways, especially if my response doesnt just contain 1 Profile.
Any Help is appreciated, watched countless tutorials but I just get more and more confused..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close. You just have to cover the situation where `externUsers` has not been loaded. (Keep in mind that everything is asynchronous in react.)

Assuming you calling the DB in a `useEffect` hook

```
const [externUsers , setExternUsers]= useState();

useEffect(()=>{
DataStore.query(Profile).then(users => setExternUsers(users));
},[]);
```

then do some handling before returning Jsx:

```
if(!externUsers) return null;
Else if(externUsers.length===0) return (<>no user</>);
Else 
return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>Home</h1>
      <p>{externUsers[0].name}</p>
      <p>{externUsers[0].position}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, unfortunately externUsers does not return an Array but a promise so I cant apply the .length attribute there :(

Comment: Updated example. Try understand and try again